# Does .NET Core support specifying solution-wide NuGet dependency versions?

Tags: .net, nuget, .net-core, dependency-management, visual-studio-2017

IIRC there was once discussion of global.json being used to specify solution-wide dependency versions in the future. The idea's that in a repo with many solutions and projects, you can bump a dependency globally by modifying a version number at one spot. Global.json no longer exists to my knowledge, so I'm wondering what alternatives exist.

For example, in projects:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Castle.Core" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  <PackageReference Include="xunit" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And some other file in the solution:

```
<Packages>
  <Package Name="Castle.Core" Version="4.0.0" />
  <Package Name="Microsoft.CSharp" Version="4.3.0" />
  <Package Name="xunit" Version="2.2.0-beta5-build3474" />
</Packages>
```

I can't find documentation on this anywhere. I ask because I'm importing projects into a monorepo and am getting hundreds of warnings like:

```
Warning     Detected package downgrade: System.IO.FileSystem from 4.3.0 to 4.0.1
```

Some hypothetical reasons I'm looking for this:

- I want to avoid scenarios where two dependencies rely on different major versions, caught at runtime rather than compilation.
- I want to avoid a massive changeset when bumping a dependency. This is mainly for code review - for example, if a 10 file PR needs a dependency bump, I don't want the PR polluted by 100 additional csproj file changes.
- I'm distributing an application with many executable components. I want an unerring way to distribute a common set of dependencies to minimize my application's file size. An error would be shipping a build that distributes multiple versions of a certain dependency.

Comment: Aside: global.json does still exist: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/preview3/tools/global-json

Comment: What is your `dotnet --version`?

Comment: I'm on the latest rc4 from this month

Comment: Not sure if global.json is used anymore. I cannot see it referenced in the .NET Core cli source code. That documentation was created in Nov 2016 which was before the RC4 SDK was released so it may be referring to the dotnet tools. If you have a set of PackageReferences that are common for a set of projects can you not just have an MSBuild import that specifies them and then just use an `<Import Project="PackageReferences.proj" />` in each project to include them? The individual projects would not have the common set of PackageReferences defined just any ones that are specific to that project.